# Nice way to nest many function calls (Unix piping) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2016

I was looking for a way to do nested function calls nicely, to avoid something like:

```
var result = function1(function2(function3()));
```

Or something like:

```
var result = function3();
result = function2(result);
result = function1(result);
```

Something like piping from Unix would be nice:

```
var result = function3() | function2() | function1();
```

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-operator-overload

Of course `|` is the bitwise or operation, this example is abstract.

Does anybody know of any way to achieve an effect like this using ES5, ES6, or ES7, without transpiling?

## Edit

Thank you T.J Crowder, torazaburo, and Bergi, you all added unique, useful, and interesting information in your answers.

Comment: If you're writing the functions yourself, you can have them return an object with all the other functions as methods. That would be slow and you'd need `.value()` or something at the end, but I guess it's cuter to some.

Comment: I am writing the functions myself, but I can't make any assumptions about the usage. They should be compartmentalized, so writing references to each function wouldn't be viable. Ideally it should work on any function, but if it's not possible, I would be open to the idea of adding something to the function to make it possible.

But again, the functions shouldn't know anything about each other.

Comment: I'm curious what environment you're going to run ES7 code in *without* transpiling... Or even ES6, right now.

Comment: The question isn't related to any specific environment, but more so I could get a feel of where Javascript is heading. I read the ES6 and ES7 planned and drafted features yesterday, and this was a question I had. It's not necessarily related to today, or tomorrow. More-so where I should invest my time. To answer the question directly, Node.js already implements most ES6 and some ES7 natively, but I assume that's because it's doing transpiling under the hood.

Comment: @Jexah: No, NodeJS uses V8, which has implemented some of ES6 (ES2015) and even bits of proposed features for ES7. Not transpiling. The V8 team are working to bring V8 in full compliance with the finalized ES2015 spec, but it's non-trivial work.

Comment: That is great to hear!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Without a helper function

I took your question initially to be doing this *without* any helper function, but your subsequent comment suggests that that's not the case. Skip down if helper functions are in scope.

Without adding any helper functions, you can use ES6 promises:

```
Promise.resolve()
    .then(function3)
    .then(function2)
    .then(function1)
    .then(result => {
  console.log("result is " + result);
});
```

It's not prettier than

```
var result = function1(function2(function3()));
```

...but at least the functions being called are listed in the order they're called, and promises are very quite flexible in multiple ways.

E.g:  [Live copy on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20function1(arg)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22function1%20called%20with%20%22%20%2B%20arg)%3B%0A%20%20return%20%22result1%22%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20function2(arg)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22function2%20called%20with%20%22%20%2B%20arg)%3B%0A%20%20return%20%22result2%22%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20function3()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22function3%20called%22)%3B%0A%20%20return%20%22result3%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0APromise.resolve()%0A%20%20%20%20.then(function3)%0A%20%20%20%20.then(function2)%0A%20%20%20%20.then(function1)%0A%20%20%20%20.then(result%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22result%20is%20%22%20%2B%20result)%3B%0A%7D)%3B%0A)

```
function function1(arg) {
  console.log("function1 called with " + arg);
  return "result1";
}
function function2(arg) {
  console.log("function2 called with " + arg);
  return "result2";
}
function function3() {
  console.log("function3 called");
  return "result3";
}

Promise.resolve()
    .then(function3)
    .then(function2)
    .then(function1)
    .then(result => {
  console.log("result is " + result);
});
```

Output:

```
function3 called
function2 called with result3
function1 called with result2
result is result1
```

---

#### With a helper function

Re your comment:

> ```
> function pipe(){
>     var str = 'Promise.resolve()';
>     for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
>         str += '.then(arguments[' + i + '])'
>     }
>     eval(str);
> }
>
>  pipe(c, b, a, result => { console.log("result is " + result); });
> ```
>
> I know pipe is a thing in fs libraries, so the function name isn't exactly great. Aside from that, is there anything glaringly wrong with this?

If you want to throw a helper function at this, there's no need at all for `eval`. For non-promise-ified functions, just do:

```
function pipe(first, ...more) {
  return more.reduce((r, f) => f(r), first());
}
```

and

```
let result = pipe(function3, function2, function1);
```

[Live copy on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20pipe(first%2C%20...more)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20more.reduce((r%2C%20f)%20%3D%3E%20f(r)%2C%20first())%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20function1(arg)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22function1%20called%20with%20%22%20%2B%20arg)%3B%0A%20%20return%20%22result1%22%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20function2(arg)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22function2%20called%20with%20%22%20%2B%20arg)%3B%0A%20%20return%20%22result2%22%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20function3()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22function3%20called%22)%3B%0A%20%20return%20%22result3%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20result%20%3D%20pipe(function3%2C%20function2%2C%20function1)%3B%0Aconsole.log(%22result%20is%20%22%20%2B%20result)%3B)

If you want to do this with promise-ified functions or a mix, then:

```
function pipe(...functions) {
  return functions.reduce((p, f) => p.then(f), Promise.resolve());
}
```

then you can call it the way you showed:

```
pipe(function3, function2, function1, result => {
    // ...
});
```

...but doing so ignores errors. Since `pipe` returns the last promise, you can use all the promise goodness

```
pipe(function3, function2, function1, result => {
    // ...
}).catch(failure => {
    // ...
});
```

or

```
pipe(function3, function2, function1)
    .then(result => {
        // ...
    })
    .catch(failure => {
        // ...
    });
```

Here's a complete example mixing simple functions and functions that return promises: [Live copy on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20pipe(...functions)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20functions.reduce((p%2C%20f)%20%3D%3E%20p.then(f)%2C%20Promise.resolve())%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20function1(arg)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22function1%20called%20with%20%22%20%2B%20arg)%3B%0A%20%20return%20%22result1%22%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20function2(arg)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22function2%20called%20with%20%22%20%2B%20arg)%3B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22result2%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20100)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20function3()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22function3%20called%22)%3B%0A%20%20return%20%22result3%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Apipe(function3%2C%20function2%2C%20function1)%0A%20%20.then(result%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Final%20result%20is%20%22%20%2B%20result)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20.catch(failure%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Failed%20with%20%22%20%2B%20failure)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B)

```
function pipe(...functions) {
    return functions.reduce((p, f) => p.then(f), Promise.resolve());
}
function function1(arg) {
    console.log("function1 called with " + arg);
    return "result1";
}
function function2(arg) {
    console.log("function2 called with " + arg);
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve("result2");
        }, 100);
    });
}
function function3() {
    console.log("function3 called");
    return "result3";
}

pipe(function3, function2, function1)
    .then(result => {
        console.log("Final result is " + result);
    })
    .catch(failure => {
        console.log("Failed with " + failure);
    });
```

Output:

```
function3 called
function2 called with result3
function1 called with result2
Final result is result1
```

Comment: Yeah it's just a detail, don't worry about it. I have used promises in the past, but only to deal with flow control of async functions. This is a good idea. After reading it, my main concern was performance, so I opened this up, and compared it to nested function calls, and the difference was negligible.

Comment: `function pipe(){
 var str = 'Promise.resolve()';
 for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
  str += '.then(arguments[' + i + '])'
 }
 eval(str);
}

pipe(c, b, a, result => {
 console.log("result is " + result);
});`

I know pipe is a thing in fs libraries, so the function name isn't exactly great. Aside from that, is there anything glaringly wrong with this?

Comment: @Jexah Why would you use promises if you write a pipe function anyway? And let's ignore that you use `eval`. And you could use rest parameters. Btw: The `pipe` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Jexah: Any time you're building up code in a string in order to `eval` it, you're probably headed the wrong way. :-) I've added a simple implementation of `pipe` to the answer above.

Comment: Please don't use promises for synchronous functions. If you want `.chain` syntax, there's nothing stopping you from using it, but don't abuse promises.

Comment: @Bergi: Note the final example, intermixing functions returning promises and ones that don't.

Comment: @Bergi: I did add a non-promise version of `pipe`, however, for a completely non-promise situation.

Comment: Yeah I know eval is bad, but I didn't think of any other way of doing it, that's why I asked for criticism on it. Thanks for this thorough solution!

Answer (score 4):

You're just composing functions. Use the `compose` function available in many libraries, or write your own, and use it as:

```
compose(function1, function2, function3) ()
```

In other words, your "pipe" operator can be thought of as a "comma" used to separate parameters in a call to compose.

Here is a real simple compose:

```
function compose(...fns) {
  var lastFunc = fns.pop();
  return function() { 
    return fns.reduceRight(result, fn) {
      return fn(result);
    }, lastFunc(...arguments));
  };
}
```

Comment: LOL, I was adding a non-promise version as well at the same time. :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a `pipe` function that is basically the well-known `compose` flipped:

```
var result = pipe(function3, function2, function1)();
```

It's not built-in (and not planned for any of the coming ES revisions), but available in many libraries like [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/0.18.0/docs/#pipe); you can trivially implement it yourself:

```
function pipe(g, ...fs) {
    if (!arguments.length) return x => x;
    if (!fs.length) return g;
    const f = pipe(...fs);
    return x => f(g(x));
}
```

---

If you are looking for new syntax, there is [an ES7 proposal](https://github.com/zenparsing/es-function-bind) that could bring some pipelining sugar to the language. It's [not settled yet](https://github.com/zenparsing/es-function-bind/issues/26) what exactly it would look like:

```
method3()::method2()::method1()
method3()->method2()->method1()
function3()->function2()->function1()
```